# How many times do I have to draw until I get $s$ red objects and $t$ white objects?

Tags: probability

We have red objects and white objects. The probability of drawing a red object or a white object is uniform, ie $0.5$. If when we draw an object we return it, then what is the average number of times we need to draw objects until we have $s$ red objects and $t$ white objects?

I understand that this is similar to the coupon collector problem. If $s,t$ are both $1$ then it is obvious that the average is $3$ since it is the random variable consisting of a sum of $G(1)$ and $G(\frac{1}{2})$. For $s=t$ in general (and $s\neq t$) I am having a bit of trouble. It doesn't matter what we get in the first $min(s,t)$ tries, we will always draw something. But then, the other tries depend on the results of the first ones, and proceeding to calculate it this way is in-feasible.

Will be glad for a hint on how to go about this. This is a homework question so please do not supply a full solution.

Comment: Is the probability to draw e.g. a white object $0.5$ by every draw?

Comment: Yes, it is uniform.

Comment: I was thinking of doing this is Bernoulli's Trials.. but that wouldnt give a 100% chance. What concept do you think needs to be applied here?

Comment: Perhaps a recurrence by looking at the first or final child?

Comment: I tried the recurrence approach and got expressions for $E(s,t)$ for $(s,t) \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}\times \mathbb{N}$. They get progressively more and more unpleasant, which doesn't fill me with great confidence that a nice closed form is possible in general. The algorithm can, in principle, be carried forward to any $s$, so it might be suitable for numerical computations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point you will end up in one of the following situations:

- The last ball drawn was red and exactly $s$ red balls are drawn in total. Next to that $q\in\{0,\dots, r-1\}$ white balls have been drawn. Let's call this event $R_q$.
- The last ball drawn was white and exactly $r$ white balls are drawn in total. Next to that $p\in\{0,\dots, s-1\}$ white balls have been drawn. Let's call this event $W_p$.

If you are in the situation first sketched then $s+q$ balls are drawn and a geometric process now starts. You can find the corresponding mean.

If you are in the situation secondly sketched then $r+p$ balls are drawn and a geometric process now starts. You can find the corresponding mean.

It comes to finding the probabilities $P(R_q)$ and $P(W_p)$ to come to a full answer.

Can you take it from here?

---

edit:

As an example to make things more clear let it be that $s=3,r=4,q=2$.

Then $R_q=R_2$ is the event: $$RRWWR\cup RWRWR\cup RWWRR\cup WRRWR\cup WRWRR\cup WWRRR$$
and it has probability $\binom422^{-5}=6\cdot2^{-5}$ to occur. Here e.g. $RRWWR$ stands for the event that first two red balls are drawn, then two white balls and then a red ball. In this situation we are ready with the red balls ($s=3$ are drawn) but yet $2$ white balls must be drawn. The average waiting time for that to happen is $2\cdot2=4$.

If $X$ denotes the waiting time in this example then  $\mathbb E(X\mid R_2)=5+2\cdot2=9$

What we are really after is finding: $$\mathbb EX=\sum_{i=0}^3\mathbb E(X\mid R_i)P(R_i)+\sum_{i=0}^2\mathbb E(X\mid W_i)P(W_i)$$

Comment: It also comes to a rather non-trivial sum made from all these ingredients. Without asking you to present the full solution (per OP's request), do you know if that sum can be evaluated to something more or less "nice"?

Comment: In the first situation, if the last ball was red then I have had any value between $t$ to $\infty$ white balls, and this last ball completes exactly $s$ reds. I don't understand what is the context of $\{0,...,r-1\}$ in your solution.

Comment: There must be some misunderstanding. I have added to make things more clear.

Comment: So for a general $q$ this gets just more and more complicated and incomprehensible. Perhaps looking at the very last drawn item until $s$ reds and $t$ whites where obtained might be simpler.

Comment: @NickPavlov I don't know. Maybe I will know once (maybe not). If it comes that far then I will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Given $s$ and $t$ the expected number $E(s,t)$ of draws is given by
$$E(s,t)=s+t+E_{\rm futile}(s,t)\ ,$$ whereby $E_{\rm futile}(s,t)$ denotes the expected number of futile draws. The full history can be viewed as a random walk in the first quadrant of the lattice. The walk starts at $(s,t)$ and for each useful draw moves one step west or one step south until it reaches the origin. As soon as the walk hits the boundary $t=0$ or $s=0$ we observe the onset of futile draws: We have to expect one futile draw per step $(k,0)\to(k-1,0)$, resp., $(0,k)\to(0,k-1)$. If the walk hits the boundary for the first time at $(r,0)$ the expected number of futile draws therefore is $r$.

We therefore have to determine the probability that the walk hits the boundary $t=0$ for the first time at the point $(r,0)$,  $\>1\leq r\leq s$. This event happens iff the walk reaches the point $(r,1)$ and then makes a step south. There are $(s+t)-(r+1)$ steps from $(s,t)$ to $(r,1)$. The probability in question therefore is
$${1\over 2^{(s+t)-(r+1)}}{(s+t)-(r+1)\choose t-1}\>\cdot{1\over2}\ .$$
Since the walk may as well hit the boundary $s=0$ we therefore obtain
$$E_{\rm futile}(s,t)={1\over 2^{s+t}}\left(\sum_{r=1}^s {(s+t)-(r+1)\choose t-1}r\>2^r+\sum_{r=1}^t {(s+t)-(r+1)\choose s-1}r\>2^r\right)\ .$$